# AS3 check if date belongs to the range?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I want to check for, if the given date belongs to two given dates.
Dates are in string format like "2015-02-19"

Comment: Try something and if you run into trouble come back, post your attempt and ask a specific question. I would start at the documentation for Date. As it stands, this question is not a good fit for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your dates are formatted as YYYY-MM-DD then they are alphabetical, so you can actually compare the strings using normal comparison operators (`<`, `>`, `==`, `<=`, `>=`), [because when both operands are strings they are compared alphabetically](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#greater_than).

So you could do this:

```
var from:String = "2015-02-02";
var to:String = "2015-06-06";

function check(date:String):Boolean {
    return date >= from && date <= to;
}

check("2015-05-05"); // true
check("2015-01-01"); // false
check("2015-07-05"); // false
check("2014-05-05"); // false
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to parse string to date. You can use RegExp for this. Pattern will looks like: `/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/`. Four digits for year, two for month, and two for day. Next, see my code. If something is not clear, please ask.

```
var begDateStr:String = "2015-02-19";
var midDateStr:String = "2015-04-19";
var endDateStr:String = "2015-06-19";

var begDate:Date = parseDate(begDateStr);
var midDate:Date = parseDate(midDateStr);
var endDate:Date = parseDate(endDateStr);

if (endDate > midDate && begDate < midDate)
{
    trace("OK");
}

function parseDate(str:String):Date
{
    var matches:Array = str.match(/(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/);

    var d:Date = new Date();
    d.setUTCFullYear(int(matches[1]), int(matches[2]) - 1, int(matches[3]));

    return d;
}
```